# ViewBag resetando ao retornar page em Razor Page

Tags: c#, razor-pages

No OnGet da página eu carrego as ViewBag assim:

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        ViewData["SGP_GRP_IdGrupoProduto"] = new SelectList(grupoProdutoService.GetAll(), "GRP_Codigo", "GRP_Descricao");
        return Page();
    }
```

Ao realizar o POST na pagina e fazer a validação do modelo, caso o modelo seja inválido ele volta a pagina mas com a viewbag vazia (null)

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Page();

        subGrupoProdutoService.Create(SubGrupoProduto);

        return RedirectToPage("../View/SubGrupo");
    }
```

O que pode ser feito para que ao realizar o return page() os dados da viewbag ainda permaneçam na pagina?

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag, ViewData não tem esse propósito, elas são para transferencia de dados de dentro para fora apenas e são descartadas junto com sua página no momento que você faz o post.

No seu caso, o que você pode fazer é atribuir novamente os dados a sua ViewData.

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewData["SGP_GRP_IdGrupoProduto"] = new SelectList(grupoProdutoService.GetAll(), "GRP_Codigo", "GRP_Descricao");
        return Page();
    }

    subGrupoProdutoService.Create(SubGrupoProduto);

    return RedirectToPage("../View/SubGrupo");
}
```